# Creative Sound Blaster X4 stays on (LEDs lit up) after laptop shutdown on a powered usb port

Tags: usb, power-management, shutdown, thunderbolt, sound-blaster

I have the following setup:

- A dual-boot windows-11/kubuntu-23.10 laptop.
- Razer Core X Chroma eGPU connected via a thunderbolt 3 port.
- Creative Sound Blaster X4 (and some other peripherals) connected to the eGPU USB 3.0 hub.

I'm still in the process of choosing and buying a GPU card, so for now the eGPU is used as a TB3 docking station.

The soundcard works fine in both Windows and Kubuntu (on PipeWire), the issue I have manifests itself upon calling a shutdown on a Kubuntu session: everything powers off nicely, however, the Sound Blaster remains lit up, but if I physically reconnect it, the lights stay off. I think this is a software/driver-related issue since powering off on a Windows session doesn't exhibit this behavior: Sound Blaster lights go down automatically. It isn't a huge deal in terms of power consumption, but it's annoying at night in a dark room when someone has to sleep there, having to power it off manually.

This is what I tried so far:

- Upgrading the Sound Blaster X4 firmware: `Creative app` for Windows reports that the latest firmware is already installed.
- Looking for TB3 power options in the BIOS (UEFI). It would make sense to have the TB3 port power off on the laptop shutdown, which would automatically solve the problem since the eGPU would just power off in this case. However sadly my BIOS (running the latest available version) doesn't have an option to control this, and the TB3 port always works in power delivery mode.
- Some USB hubs allow to power off selected USB ports programmatically, so powering off the required port on shutdown would be a viable solution. Sadly [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) reports that is not the case with the eGPU hub (reports no compatible hubs found).
- Looking for specific Razer eGPU drivers for Linux: I found [openrazer](https://openrazer.github.io), but it seems to allow for control of the eGPU's RGB lighting only: at least clients like [RazerGenie](https://github.com/z3ntu/RazerGenie) expose lighting setup only.
- Looking for Sound Blaster X4 specific Linux drivers/control apps, couldn't find any.
- Messing with `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level` as per different StackOverflow sources like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux), no luck too.
- Trying the latest mainline Linux kernel (currently 6.6.1), using `Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer` didn't change anything.

I should also add that a Trust GXT 170 RGB-lit computer mouse, connected to the same hub, powers the LEDs off nicely on shutdown from both Windows and Linux.

Any leads or clues are greatly appreciated, I'm totally out of ideas.